# Split record with delimited value

Tags: oracle

I need to separate delimited string value into separate rows
What I need is:

```
FAILUREID  TNO
1          t01
1          t02
1          t03
2          t04
2          t05
```

But using the code below I receided

```
1   t01
1   t02
1   t03
1   t03
1   t03
1   t02
1   t03
2   t04
2   t05
2   t05
```

Some lines are duplicated. Where is the bug in the code below, How to fix it ?  ( distinct is not a solution)

```
with data as 
( select 1 as FailureID
        ,'t01;t02;t03' as Tickets
  from dual
  union 
  select 2 
        ,'t04;t05'
    from dual
)
select   FailureID
        ,regexp_substr(Tickets, '[^;]+', 1, level) as TNO
from data
connect by regexp_substr(tickets, '[^;]+', 1, level) is not null
order by failureid
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how (the difference begins at line #13):

```
SQL> with data as
  2  ( select 1 as FailureID
  3          ,'t01;t02;t03' as Tickets
  4    from dual
  5    union
  6    select 2
  7          ,'t04;t05'
  8      from dual
  9  )
 10  select   FailureID
 11          ,regexp_substr(Tickets, '[^;]+', 1, column_value) as TNO
 12  from data
 13  cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 14                                 connect by level <= regexp_count(tickets, ';') + 1
 15                                ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 16  order by failureid;

 FAILUREID TNO
---------- -----------
         1 t01
         1 t02
         1 t03
         2 t04
         2 t05

SQL>
```